# Error from socket() call

Tags: c, linux, sockets, uclibc

I wanted to add IPv6 support for my program and came across odd error. I want to open socket which accepts connections. Here is my scenario:

First I use getaddrinfo() to find socket configuration:

```
struct addrinfo hint, *info = NULL;

memset((void *)&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((error = getaddrinfo(NULL, "1234", &hint, &info))) {
    /* some error handling */
}
```

I gen non-NULL result in `info`. Then I want to create socket:

```
socket(info->ai_family, info->ai_socktype, info->ai_protocol)
```

Here I get `-1`

```
strerror(errno)
```

returns `Address family not supported by protocol`

I thought that `getaddrinfo()` returns only addresses that can be bound and I would expect it to return NULL in this case. What am I missing?

I want to add that my eth0 does not have IPv6 address right now. I am using uClibc 0.9.32

Comment: You get what you ask for ... otherwise remove `hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `AI_ADDRCONFIG` to ai_flags to make sure it doesn't return address families unsupported by the kernel. I pretty much always add that flag nowadays.

If you want to support kernels without IPv6 you'll have to avoid setting ai_family to AF_INET6. Instead you have to listen on all the returned addresses, and make sure to set IPV6_V6ONLY on the AF_INET6 ones. There's no guarantee that the AF_INET6 address will be returned first, unfortunately.

Comment: This saved my bacon today!  Thank you!

Comment: @gubblebozer Glad to help. I want to note that by now I always first try passing `AF_INET6` to getaddrinfo. If that or the following socket call fails I fallback to `AF_INET`. It's more code but having a single listen socket makes things easier elsewhere (make sure to turn _off_ IPV6_V6ONLY if you do this).

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo` returns a linked list of `struct addrinfo` objects, which you can traverse using the `ai_next` member. You should try each returned `addrinfo` object in turn until you get a connection (or hit `NULL`/end of list).